# please i need places where i can download tutorials on php, html, css

Tags: php, html, css

please i need direct downloading links to download tutorial pdf on php, html, css, and the rest of them. I live in Nigeria and the link is not ok, so i want to enhance it with he use of downloading manager. I'll be most greatful.

Dotun

Comment: For god sake, if any one will decide to answer here - don't point to w3sch00ls, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books

You will find plenty of free books there!

Answer (score 1):

Good general purpose reference materials on w3schools.com.

Comment: For HTML as an tag and attribute reference, sure.  For CSS, maybe.  For PHP, hell no.  Their PHP materials are full of worst practices and vulnerabilities.  See also http://w3fools.com/

Comment: blame google - i'm too busy to click ouside the top 3 when i need a factoid

Comment: any reason to answer if you don't know what exactly to say? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This was my favorite site for learning PHP, http://www.tizag.com/